# OpenCV crop image and display the original with crop removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have a image as follows:

[image]

On this image I am running a face detection code as follows:
More details incase you want to run this code are [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-in-2-minutes-using-opencv-python-90f89d7c0f81)

Face detector:

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Read the input image
img = cv2.imread('5.jpg')

# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

# Draw rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x-20, y-70), (x + w + 50, y + h + 50), (255, 0, 0), 2)

crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]


cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", crop_img)
```

As a output of this code image I get

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

In the output I want the entire image but with the face removed. How to achieve this result ?

Comment: Overwrite the pixels within the rectangle with 1’s in the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use numpy to overwrite the pixels:

```
img[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w, 0] = 0
img[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w, 1] = 0
img[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w, 2] = 0
```

note that numpy has a strange indexing system that rows are first, columns second (opposite to common indexing)

Comment: I tried your code it gives me black mask not white (as shown in the question) any idea what this is so ? also I tried changing 0 to 1 in your above code but I get same black output

Comment: img[y-60:y+h+80, x-20:x+w+50, 0] = 255
img[y-60:y+h+80, x-20:x+w+50, 1] = 255
img[y-60:y+h+80, x-20:x+w+50, 2] = 255

Comment: Better use `img[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w, :] = 255` or even `img[y1:y1+h, x1:x1+w] = 255`

Comment: while true, i gave it like this to allow any colour